# Python Pandas datasets - Having integers values in new column by making a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to output in a new column integers values (labels/classes) based on labels of another column in my dataset. Actually I did it by creating new columns (numerical column heading) for each class with boolean values in them, so then I can use these to create the new class column with numerical values. But I was trying to do it with a dictionary, which I think it is a good and faster way.

If I run a code like this:

```
x=df['Item_Type'].value_counts()
item_type_mapping={}
item_list=x.index
for i in range(0,len(item_list)):
    item_type_mapping[item_list[i]]=i
```

It generates the dictionary, but then if I run:

```
df['Item_Type']=df['Item_Type'].map(lambda x:item_type_mapping[x])
```

or

```
df['New_column']=[item_type_mapping[item] for item in data.Item_Type]
```

It displays `KeyError=None`

Anybody know why this occurs? I think that's strange since the dictionary has been created and I can see it through my variables

Thanks

**Edit 1**
@Fourier
simply I have this column:

```
| Item_type|
| -------- |
| Nino     |
| Nino     |
| Nino     |
| Pasquale |
| Franco   |
| Franco   |
```

and then I need the same column or a new one to display:

```
| Item_type| New_column |
| -------- | ---------- |
| Nino     | 1          |
| Nino     | 1          |
| Nino     | 1          |
| Pasquale | 2          |
| Franco   | 3          |  
| Franco   | 3          |
```

Comment: Can you please provide some minimal example of the data so we can see what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have edited my question. See above

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me, but what you're trying to do is already provided by pandas as [Categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Type': list('abca')})
df['New_column'] = df.Item_Type.astype('category').cat.codes
```

Result:

```
  Item_Type  New_column
0         a           0
1         b           1
2         c           2
3         a           0
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Anyway the problem is that in reality dataframes I am working on are huge, and I don't really know how many items there are in **Item_type** column. This is why I am trying a cicle with df.value_counts(). So I guess I might try Pandas Categorical data with a cicle on the list referred to the dictionary